# Salesforce login failed for honeycomb devices

Tags: android, authentication, salesforce, remote-access

while integrating salesforce into my android app using url

> /services/oauth2/authorize?display=mobile&response_type=token&client_id=my_consumer_key_from_salesforce&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success

I am able to see the salesforce log in page. But when clicking on the 'Allow' button in the next page,i get this message 'Remote Access Authorization' error. And it is not being redirected to my Activty page. The callback url is given as 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success'. This happens when i try it in a honeycomb device(Samsung Galaxy 10"). Whereas the redirection part works properly in Android 2.2 devices.

Please provide a solution for this issue? Or guide me in the proper path.

Comment: Are you using the mobile SDK or something else?

Comment: I am using the mobile SDK itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the reason that shouldOverrideUrlLoading() of WebView that is loading the salesforce url not getting triggered. If you are using this method, replace it with onPageStarted() and copy and paste the code that was in shouldOverrideUrlLoading().

Thanks,
Regards,
Abi